# React: No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the above error from the code:

```
<EditableContainer handleFn={this.onSaveTitle} component={FieldStyle}>{props.child}</EditableContainer>
```

```
class EditableContainer extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render () {
        const {children, ...rest} = this.props
        const {edit} = this.state

        if (edit) {
            return (
                <Component
                    autoFocus
                    onBlur={this.handleBlur.bind(this)}
                    value={this.state.children}
                    onChange={this.handleOnChange}
                    render={(props) => this.props.component.render(props)}
                />
            )
        } 
}
```

```
class FieldStyle extends React.Component<any, any> { 
    render () {
        const {autoFocus, ...rest} = this.props

        // auto focus
        const ref = autoFocus ? (ref) => { this.ref = ref } : null
        return (
            <TextField
                ref={ref}
                type="text"
                {...rest}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to specify which component should be loaded from `EditableContainer` to the actual component itself using React's `Component` which has a `component` prop. However, I get the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably change your `props` to this (notice the capital `C` in `Component`):

```js
<EditableContainer handleFn={this.onSaveTitle} Component={FieldStyle}>{props.child}</EditableContainer>
```

You need to destructure `Component` out of `this.props` in `EditableContainer` like this:

```js
const {children, Component, ...rest} = this.props
```